# IOException java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1(port 5000):connect failed:ECONNREFUSED(Connection Refused)

Tags: java, android, sockets

Trying to do android socket programming based on this tutorial 
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

I have my firewall turned off and anti virus disabled. If I make my server address to 127.0.0.1 I get the error in the title. If I make it my local IP address,it just sits at socket going to be created.I have tried it without and with port forwarding and setting it to the same port.

Client

```
package com.bennatpjose.androidsocketclient;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Socket socket;
    private TextView text;
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.52.7.179";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Thread should be fired");

}

public void onClick(View view) {
    try {

        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        String str = et.getText().toString();
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"\n"+"Click Event "+str);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"\n"+"Next is out.println("+str+")");
        out.println(str);
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"\n"+"out.println("+str+")");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"\nPrint Writer UnknownHostException "+e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"\nPrint Writer IOException "+e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"\nPrint Writer Exception "+e.toString());
    }
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"\nInside client thread run method ");
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
//If I set address to my local ip it just sits here and doesn't show socket created.


text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"\n"+serverAddr +" Socket going to be Created");
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"\n"+socket.toString() +"Socket Created");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"\nClient Thread UnknownHostException "+e1.toString());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"\nClient Thread IOException "+e1.toString());
            }catch (Exception e1) {
                text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"\nClient Thread Exception "+e1.toString());
            }
    }

}
```

}

Server

```
package com.bennatpjose.androidsocketserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    Handler updateConversationHandler;

    Thread serverThread = null;

    private TextView text;

    public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"onCreate method started");
        updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

        this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        this.serverThread.start();
        text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"\n"+"serverThread started");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {

        serverSocket.close();
        text.setText("!!Socket Stopped!!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    text.setText(text.getText().toString()+socket+"\n");

                    CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                    new Thread(commThread).start();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

        private Socket clientSocket;

        private BufferedReader input;

        public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

            try {

                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    String read = input.readLine();

                    updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
        private String msg;

        public updateUIThread(String str) {
            this.msg = str;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I should probably add that I am running it in two AVD's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out. One of the mistakes I did was replacing the SERVER_IP with my local ip where as I should have left it at 10.0.2.2 since its a special loopback address android emulators.
10.0.2.2    Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)

You also have to run the server first,set the port redirection and then  run the client.

Look up Emulator networking section at http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html